# Can you have multiple assertEquals(answer, result) in the same junit test?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Doing some junit testing for an assignment. Just wondering if it's possible to have multiple assertEquals() statements in the same test? When it passes, does that mean that it will fail if one assertEquals statement fails? Or does it only take one assertEquals() statement?

```
    car3 = new Car("gargle", 45, false);
    car4 = new Car("cheese", 45, true);
    moto3 = new MotorCycle("ass", 45);

    assertEquals(true, carPark.spacesAvailable(car3));
    assertEquals(true, carPark.spacesAvailable(car4));
    assertEquals(true, carPark.spacesAvailable(moto3));
```

Will only the first assertEquals be used or will all be used

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  Set it up so that the first assertion is true and the second one is false, then see what happens.

Answer (score 11):

All asserts will be run, in order. The first assertion to fail causes the test to fail and no further asserts are run after that.

[AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core) has a mechanism which allows to run all assertions, whether they succeed or fail:

```
final SoftAssertions soft = new SoftAssertions();
soft.assertThat(...);
soft.assertThat(...);
soft.assertThat(...);
soft.assertAll();
```

This will report *all* assertions which fail on `.assertAll()`. [Link to javadoc](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.html).

---

**EDIT** Starting with 2.0.0 (Java 7+ only) there is also `AutoCloseableSoftAssertions`, which means you don't need to `.assertAll()` at the end:

```
try (
    final AutoCloseableSoftAssertions soft
        = new AutoCloseableSoftAssertions();
) {
    soft.assertThat(thePope).isSaint(); // or whatever
} // <--- .assertAll() here!
```

Comment: +1 It would be better, if you can add a link to `AssertJ` API

Comment: If you don't want to use external library AssertJ, and are using Junit 4.7 or above, you might want to have a look at ErrorCollector https://www.guru99.com/junit-errorcollector.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have many different assert statements inside of j/x/n Unit tests. 
However, as you have found, should any of the asserts fail, the entire testMethod will fail as a result.

As it so happens, inside of a testMethod the test runner will begin executing the assert statements. As soon as one fails the testMethod will return, not executing any additional asserts.

Answer (score 2):

Hi dear i want to give you one suggestion if you want to use multiple assert then. It would be better if there is use of "if else" condition for multiple AssertTrue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have more than one assertEquals in one unittest. The unit test fails if one of the assertEquals returns false.